# Lookup would require extrapolation into the future

Tags: ros, transforms, ros-melodic, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1576960606.876893997 but the latest data is at time 1576960578.443333626.

The request time seems to be correct. However, the latest data seems to update slowly. When I open Rvis, it takes about 15 second to update the trasform. I wonder if I need to synchonize the timer. However should I do it.

Note: I add my code with waitForTransform. However, the error still exists.

now = rospy.Time.now()
#listener = tf.TransformListener()
self.listener.waitForTransform(self.robot_link, target_link, now, rospy.Duration(0.1))
(trans,rot) = self.listener.lookupTransform(self.robot_link, target_link, now)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340507/lookup-would-require-extrapolation-into-the-future/) by [Chao Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/50395/chao-chen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2019-12-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved. You need to synchronize the time on your laptop with the platform you are using.

---

Originally posted by [Chao Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/50395/chao-chen/) with karma: 56 on 2020-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0